# Facebook attachment data format for "media" key. (related to Posting Image+Text on friend's wall )

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, ios4, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to post some data at one of the friend from my friend list . 
I am able to post some text on my friend's wall.But it fails to post the image and other data . (Presentl I can only see the text for key "message" and rest of the part does not appear in the post.

```
SBJSON *jsonWriter = [[SBJSON new] autorelease];

/*
 Action LInks
 */
NSDictionary* actionLinks = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                       @"Always Running",@"text",@"http://itsti.me/",@"href", nil], nil];
//Json Object Conversion
NSString *actionLinksStr = [jsonWriter stringWithObject:actionLinks];


/*
 Media Data in this case an image.
*/
**NSMutableDictionary *dictMedia=[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"image",@"type",@"http://www.facebook.com/images/devsite/iphone_connect_btn.jpg",@"src",@"www.fizzysoftware.com",@"href", nil];
NSArray *mediaArray=[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:dictMedia, nil];
NSString *mediaJsonString=[jsonWriter stringWithObject:mediaArray]; // error:actionLinksStr] 

//Attatchment Data :Include media data,action link etc.

NSDictionary* attachment = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                            @"First Title", @"name",
                            @"This is the subtitle", @"caption",
                            @"This is is description", @"description",
                           mediaJsonString, @"media", nil];

//Json conversion of the attachment data.
NSString *attachmentStr = [jsonWriter stringWithObject:attachment];**

//Main parameter
NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               @"Share on Facebook",  @"message",
                               actionLinksStr, @"action_links",
                               attachmentStr, @"attachment",
                               nil];

 //Post to friend's wall, whose uid is friend_uid
[ _facebook requestWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"friend_uid/feed/"] andParams:params
 andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];
```

Any suggestions where I am mistaking in sending the attachment. I am able to only see the "message" part of the **param** in my post and none of the attachment data is shown in the post. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using the new approach to open a feed dialog and set the "to" (used to be target) parameter along with the rest of the attachments directly as params.

```
  NSDictionary* params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                             @"some facebook id", @"to",
                             @"http://yourpage.com", @"link",
                             @"http://yourpage.com/image.png", @"picture",
                             @"the name", @"name",
                             @"the caption", @"caption",
                             @"the description", @"description",
                             nil];
  [_facebook dialog: @"feed" andParams: params andDelegate: self];
```

Here you have some documentation regarding the feed dialog.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

If you are posting directly, you should be doing something like this:

```
[_facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"some facebook id/feed"
                      andParams:params 
                  andHttpMethod:@"POST" 
                    andDelegate:self];
```

Doc regarding direct posts:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#posts

Hope this helps.